# Проблема с методом SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Использую метод `SaveChanges` чтобы сохранить изменения, внесенные пользователем на сайте. На локальном сервере все работает хорошо, как только загружаю на реальный сервер - метод вылетает на строке с `db.SaveChangesAsync();`
Вот код самого метода:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<string> SaveChanges(string email, string name, string avatar, string password)
{
    UserModel user = await db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.EmailUser == User.Identity.Name);
    List<UserModel> users = db.Users.ToList().FindAll(u => u.EmailUser == email);

    user.EmailUser = email;
    user.NameUser = name;
    user.AvatarUser = avatar;
    user.Password = password;

    db.Users.Update(user);

    await db.SaveChangesAsync(true);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("saved");
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `метод вылетает на строке с db.SaveChanges();` у вас в коде нет метода `SaveChanges`, ну и вы не пишете текст ошибки, с которой вылетает

Comment: Эта строка `UserModel user = await db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...)` может вернуть `user == null`, но вы не проверяете этот случай, а продолжаете работать с ним как не в чем ни бывало. Вторая строка `... users = db.Users.ToList().FindAll(...)` бессмысленна, т.к. вы результат все равно нигде не используете, да еще сама по себе плохая, т.к. всех юзеров сначала выдергиваете в List, а потом что-то начинаете в них искать. А представьте на минуту, если пользователей миллион, надо ли нагружать так сервер СУБД и сеть, чтоб выдергивать такую коллекцию, из которой потом выбрать одного или двух?

Answer (score 1):

метод [`SaveChangesAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync) не принимает аргументы, лиюбо принимает `CancellationToken`, либо (`bool`,`CancellationToken)`.
Пример использование:

```
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

и обычно в Task возвращают не `string`, а

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveChanges(string email, string name, string avatar, string password)
{
    return Content("saved");
}
```

Так же посмотрите информацию, которую возвращает этот метод (ошибку например). Без ошибки не понятно что не так.

Comment: @AK исправился )

Comment: Я пробовала и без аргументов, все равно не работает. По поводу возвращающего значения тоже странно, никогда не было проблем с типами.. На сервере возвращает просто 400Bad Request и ничего больше :с

Comment: @IrinaKachurina значит проверяйте каждую строчку...дело не в сохранении...а в том что до него

Comment: Я проверяла каждую строчку, именно на сохранении выскакивает ошибка)

Comment: @IrinaKachurina сделайте проверку на хотябы возможные ошибки в функции вашей

Comment: Ошибку таки нашла. На сервере бд находилась в папке, доступной только на чтение, отсюда и невозможность что-либо перезаписать/добавить. Спасибо, за помощь)